# mediawiki syntax parser for android

Tags: java, android, api, parsing, mediawiki

I need some help fetching the content of a mediawiki page and displaying it in my android app. I've found that mediawiki has a api which can export the markup text, but I need someway to parse it.

Other solutions are also welcome, but I don't just want to include the whole page (with menus and everything) as a webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the HTML for just the content section (i.e. not including the menus and everything) by specifying [`action=render`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#Actions) when fetching the page normally. You can get about the same result using the API's [`action=parse`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse). In either case, you could then supply your own framing HTML, stylesheets, and the like for proper display to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the wiki you may be best served by using the mobile format that wikipedia uses.  Otherwise it will depend on what the markup text it returns looks like.  If the markup is what you would see in the wiki editor you may have issues.  Wikipedia for example make extensive use of templates (or whatever they call them).  I'm not sure if you can do much if you don't have the actual temple code behind that.

You also might want to look at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Markup_spec if you are headed down this path.